# FPGA PCIe EP to NVMe SSD in a Host environment

Tags: pci-express, nvme

I have a FPGA data acquisition card that plugs into the PCIe slot in a typical high-end Windows/Linux workstation.  I would like to transfer data coming into the FPGA to an NVMe drive plugged into another PCIe slot.

Do I need an NVMe Host controller in my FPGA to write directly to the NVMe drive?

Is it possible to get the NVMe controller in the Host to setup a DMA xfer between the FPGA and NVMe drive and then get out of the way?

I am envisioning zero copy transfers to SSD i.e. without using any Host processing or memory.
Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because after doing some searching the question may be more suited for a different stack, for example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/129708

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to perform a Peer-to-peer DMA (P2PDMA) operation, which offloads the DMA traffic from the CPU.  See [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/931668/) for some background.  Linux kernel support [here](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/pci/p2pdma.html).

> Do I need an NVMe Host controller in my FPGA to write directly to the
> NVMe drive?

You need some sort of controller to allow the P2PDMA operation to occur without a CPU.

> Is it possible to get the NVMe controller in the Host to setup a DMA
> xfer between the FPGA and NVMe drive and then get out of the way?

I have seen some NoLoad accelerators such as [Eideticom](https://www.flashmemorysummit.com/English/Collaterals/Proceedings/2018/20180809_ENST-301A-1_Gibb.pdf).  You may find [this](https://www.eideticom.com/uploads/attachments/2019/07/29/amd_eideticom_solution_brief.pdf) brief useful as well.  See another Eideticom partner solution [here](https://www.bittware.com/resources/nvme-storage/).

> Using Eideticom’s NoLoad NVM Express Computational Storage Processor
> and the Linux® p2pdma framework removes 100% of DMA traffic from the
> CPU’s memory subsystem. This vastly improves the performance of
> applications running on the CPU.